# Is there a published standard for 'euro modules'?

Tags: mains, standard, outlet

Variously called 'Euro modules', 'Euromods', 'Euro modular', these are 'standard' sized units (1U, 2U, ..) that slot into face plates - e.g. a 1-gang face plate can take 2U; 2-gang fits 4U - that can then essentially have any data, power, switch, whatever, on the modular unit instead of having a custom faceplate for every imaginable combination (except the one you want of course!).

[image: 'Euro module' 1U and 2U modular units]

(Image from http://www.retrotouch.co.uk)

Is this just a de facto industry standard, manufacturers want to make modules to sell you even if a competitor made your faceplate, or is there an actual BS/IEC/something standard for them?

I haven't had any luck finding one. They're not even on Wikipedia (not to be confused with 'eurorack' or its 'euro modules' which seems to be much bigger and to do with musical synthesisers) that I can find - perhaps there's another/standard name for them that I don't know?

Comment: No, you have to pick a manufacturer and stay with them. Like cars if you buy a bmw then you can’t fit an engine from a Lada in to it - well you can but takes a lot of messing about - same as jumping suppliers of faceplates etc.

Comment: @Solar Mike no you don't though. It's at least a *de facto* standard; my question is whether it's something more.

Comment: Unanswered 2019 duplicate (that I actually commented on at the time, d'oh) over on https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/177403/euro-modules-is-there-an-actual-standard-for-them-or-are-they-just-a-de-facto

Comment: I can only add that Click Scolmore make a range of these called new media, which may be why Euro module isn’t in Wikipedia, perhaps it is a trade name of BG